# Online Word breaks when inserting a content control

Tags: ms-office, office-js

I have tested this with Script Lab (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/) and it seems saving a document (automatically) to One Drive breaks Word if the document has something in it inserted through an add in (reproduced with a different add in that uses the same piece of code).

This is the code for Script Lab:

```
$("#run").click(run);

var content = '<span>Hello, World!</span>';

async function run() {
    Word.run(function (context) {
        var range = context.document.getSelection();
        var cc = range.insertContentControl();
        var ccRange = cc.insertHtml(content, 'replace');
        cc.tag = 'citation';
        cc.select('end');
        context.load(cc);
        context.load(range);
        context.load(ccRange);

        return context.sync();
    })
}
```

The code above successfully inserts `content` to selection. However, if I wait for a couple of moments after inserting, Word breaks on saving and asks me to send an error report. Same code does not produce any errors on the desktop version of Word. Also, same piece of code has been used by our add in for months now without any issues until now.

Any ideas what is this about? Is there something wrong with the online version of Word or should the code for inserting be somehow updated?

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the issue that you've described in Word Online and I don't see any obvious problems with your code.  I'd suggest that you report this issue to the product team by logging an issue in the [OfficeDev/office-js](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) GitHub repository, and include a link to this Stack Overflow post, so that this post can be updated when the issue is resolved.

Comment: @KimBrandl thanks! I see you opened something very similar recently - issue 53. Is that the same thing?

Comment: Even though it's also related to problems with Content Controls in Word Online, [Issue #53](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/53) seems like a different issue that what you've described. I'd suggest that you open a new issue for this.

Comment: Thank you for opening the issue in GitHub, @dnmh.  For others' reference, here's the link to the corresponding GitHub issue: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/54.

Comment: it seems the issue still arise